# Find the area of ​the shaded region $CEOD$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, area, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In figure $O$ and $O_1$ are centers, $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AO_1}=\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{O_1B}$. If $AD = 4\sqrt2$. Calculate the area of ​​the shaded region. (Answer: $2(4-\sqrt2)$)
>
> [image]

My progress:

$\angle AOD = 90^\circ$

$[ECOD] = [AOD] - [AEC]$

$\triangle AEC \sim \triangle AOD \implies \dfrac{AE}{AO} = \dfrac{AC}{4\sqrt2} = \dfrac{EC}{OD}$

$\dfrac{[AEC]}{[AOD]}=\dfrac{AC\cdot AE}{4\sqrt2\cdot AO}$

$[ECOD] = \dfrac{OD+EC}{2}\cdot OE$

$[AOD] = \dfrac{AO\cdot OD}{2}$

$[AEC] =\dfrac{AE\cdot EC}{2} $

I couldn't see more...???

Comment: How do you know that $\angle AOD=90^\circ$. Isn't that assuming that $O, O_1, D$ are aligned, or that $D$ is the midpoint of the arc $\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{BA}$? Please include the complete problem statement :)

Comment: Hint : $O_1OA$ is right isosceles. So radii of two circles are in ratio $\sqrt{2}:1$

Comment: @Dr.Mathva $O$ is center lying on chord $AB$ of smaller circle. Hence the conclusion. $A,O,B$ are to be assumed collinear, it seems.

Comment: @MyMolecules I made a correction in the AD value

Comment: As @MyMolecules said, make an attempt using ratio of radii of circles.

Comment: @Dr.Mathva if $O$ is center$\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{AO1}=\overset{\LARGE{\frown}}{O1B}$ therefore $OO1$ is a perpendicular ($\angle AO1=90^o$

Comment: Also you can use power of point $D$ or drop a perp from $O$ to $AC$ and use similar triangles...

Comment: Why do you have $AC/4$ from similarity? In the text $AD=4\sqrt 2$

Comment: @Andrei I already made the correction thanks for alert

Comment: Use $AEC \sim AOD$ to express $[AEC]$ in terms of $[AOD]$. You need to compute $CE$ using power of point $D$ as @MathLover said. Sorry, I have to go away for today.

Comment: @MyMolecules  I found area of ​​the $\triangle ADO$ .Which relation do I use to find the area of ​​the $\triangle AEC$?

Comment: Once you have radius you know $[AOD]$ and then using $AC$, shaded area is $~[AOD] - \frac{AC^2}{AD^2} [AOD]$

Comment: @MathLover thnals for hint..I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $OO_1=R$. Then $AO_1=R\sqrt 2$ (right angle isosceles triangle). Since $O_1A=O_1D$ (radii of the big circle), you have $OD=R+R\sqrt 2$. In $\triangle ADO$ you can apply Pythagoras:$$AD^2=AO^2+DO^2=R^2+R^2(1+\sqrt 2)^2$$so $$32=R^2(1+1+2+2\sqrt 2)$$simplify it to get $$R=\sqrt{16-8\sqrt 2}$$and $$OD=\sqrt{16+8\sqrt 2}$$
Now draw the perpendicular from $O$ to $AC$ in $P$. $\triangle APO\sim\triangle AOD$. $$AP=\frac{AC}2$$
and $$\frac{AP}{AO}=\frac{AO}{AD}$$
Therefore $$AC=\frac{2R^2}{4\sqrt 2}=4\sqrt 2-4$$
You can now continue how you started with similar triangles to get $AE$ and $EC$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Your $AC$ is wrong...$AC = 4\sqrt2-4$

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Let $r$ be the radius of the smaller circle, so the radius of the larger circle is $r\sqrt{2}$.

Firstly, $$\angle AO_1O=45^o\implies \angle ADO=22\frac12^o$$
So $$\angle DAO=67\frac12^o=\angle ACO$$
$$\implies \angle AOC=45^o\implies CE=EO=\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}$$

The shaded area is then $$T=\frac12EO(CE+DO)=\frac12\cdot\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}+r+r\sqrt{2})$$
$$\implies T=\frac14r^2(3+\sqrt{2})$$

However, due to Pythagoras, $$r^2+(r\sqrt{2}+r)^2=(4\sqrt{2})^2$$
$$\implies r^2=\frac{32}{4+2\sqrt{2}}=8(2-\sqrt{2})$$

Hence $$T=\frac14(3+\sqrt{2})\cdot8(2-\sqrt{2})=2(4-\sqrt{2})$$

Comment: I like your first part of the answer $CE=EO=r/\sqrt 2$. Slightly more elegant than my approach.

Comment: @petaarantes you are welcome

Comment: @Andrei. Thanks, although there is probably an even slicker way of doing this question, but I'm not sure what that is...